# Intuition behind UTT's internal logic

Tags: lo.logic, type-theory, lambda-calculus, dependent-type, typed-lambda-calculus

The "internal logic" of type theory UTT is [defined](https://global.oup.com/academic/product/computation-and-reasoning-9780198538356?cc=us&lang=en&) in [LF](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/52663/confusion-about-t-and-el-when-defining-universes-in-lf?noredirect=1&lq=1) as follows:

[image]

What's the intuition behind this definition? I can kind of understand the declaration of the the first three constants - we have the universe of propositions, and to every proposition (i.e., every object of type $Prop$) there corresponds a type of its proofs via $\textbf{Prf}$ (here, I also don't have intuition on why this would be a reasonable/useful thing to have); $\forall$ stands for the usual universal quantification. But what's the intuition behind $(9.4), (9.5), (9.6)$?

And by the way, what exactly does the term "internal logic" mean? Maybe there isn't a rigorous definition of this term, but for example why doesn't the "internal logic" described above say anything about predicative universes (which also exist in UTT; but they are described [separately](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uY8AU.png), after the introduction of internal logic)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. $\mathit{Prop}$ is a universe and $\mathrm{Prf}$ is its decoding function. (Often called $T$ for Tarski-style universe.)
2. $\Lambda$ is the introduction rule for universal quantification.
3. $\mathbf{E}_\forall$ is the elimination rule for universal quantification.
4. Equation (9.6) is the computation rule explaining what happens when we eliminate an introduction form.

You should compare these rules with the [rules for universal quantifiers in type theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/universal+quantifier#in_dependent_type_theory).

[Internal logic](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+logic)is a broad term that cannot be explained in this answer. I will not even try.

Comment: Many thanks. Do you happen to know a non-HoTT-oriented source (maybe a textbook) that discusses universal quantifiers in dependent type theory?

Comment: You could [go to the source](https://github.com/michaelt/martin-lof), for instance around pages 13 and 17 of the [Padova notes](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/michaelt/martin-lof/master/pdfs/Bibliopolis-Book-retypeset-1984.pdf).